# AWS Console - EC2 Instances not visible to other member's

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am member of an organisation account in AWS. I have created two EC2 instance in us-east-1 region. But other team members are not able to see this EC2 instance in Management console.

Since infrastructure or assets is managed by a team and not individuals we need to have a team view for all that is in use. The admin users should have ability to view any instance, that is what we want to achieve here. The problem is at present the user who created the EC2 instance is the only user who is able to see EC2 instance in console.

Below is the account details as it gets displayed in AWS Management Console -

[image: Account Details]

Below is the screen shot which confirms that the user belongs to an organisation -

[image: Organisation Account]

Can any one suggest how can this be achieved?

Comment: your account is `aws organization account` but which type of organization? `Consolidated Billing` or `Full Features`. You can only apply for `Full Features` organization type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If users have the ability to view *any* instances in the EC2 management console, then they will see *all* instances in the console.

If they can see *some* instances (which proves they have the right permission to view instances), but some instances are not appearing then the problem might be one of:

- The 'missing' instance was launched in a different account
- The 'missing' instance was launched in a different region than you are viewing in the console
- There is a filter active on the listing that is limiting the instances shown

You could also try using the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) `aws ec2 describe-instances` command to list instances to verify that the same information is returned for different credentials. (That is, run it as different users and compare the output.)

**Bottom line:** You should either see them all or see none (due to insufficient permissions to list instances). It is not possible to only view *some*.

Comment: The admin users should have ability to view any instance, that is what we want to achieve here. The problem is at present the user who created the EC2 instance is the only user who is able to see EC2 instance in console.

Comment: That is not possible. A person will either see ALL instances or NO instances. Please see my list above to diagnose the situation. If you disagree, please add screenshots to your question to show your situation. (You can Edit your question at any time.)

Comment: **Tip:** Look in the top-right corner to see the account number and region. Make sure the account number and region are showing the same value for both users.

Comment: The region is us-east-1 i.e US East (N. Virginia), what you mean by the account number are you referring to account id? If so can two separate users account id be same? Thanks for your response and support.

Comment: The account number normally appears as part of your username in the menu to the left of the Region menu, eg *jeet@123456789012*. If it does not display that way, then pull-down the menu to the left of the region menu, and the Account will be displayed. Make sure that both users have the same Account showing, and the same Region showing. The Account is for your organization. Multiple users can be created within one account.

Comment: I have added a screen shot as it gets displayed in management console. Please let me know in case if I am looking at right place.

Comment: That's interesting. It differs from my screen. In that case, go into **My Account** to see your account number. Do that for both the person who *can* see the instance and the person who *can't* see the instance. See whether they are the same Account ID and the same region (N.Virginia).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156007/discussion-between-jeet-and-john-rotenstein).